# Google search to PDF using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm trying to write VBA code to automate the process of running Google searches against specific topics and saving the first two pages of results as a PDF.

I'm new to coding and so any help would be massively appreciated. The steps I think I need to follow are:

1. Set up a loop which iterates through a list of search items (likely listed down column A in excel)
2. For each item in the list:

   - Open up Internet Explorer (in the background without opening on screen)
   - Search for the item in Google
   - Wait for the page to fully load
   - Export the first page of results as a PDF (to a hard-coded location)
   - Move to the second page of Google results
   - Wait for the page to fully load
   - Export the second page of results as a PDF
   - Quit the Internet Explorer application
3. Move to the next item in the list and repeat the above

I've created the module which opens up Internet Explorer using the following, but I'm struggling with the loop and export to PDF components:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=testing&meta="
IE.Visible = False
Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

In terms of exporting to PDF I've got software called PDFCreator which is what I'll need to use for the PDF export.

Any ideas on whether the above is possible? Many thanks.